# Как получить доступ к DOM iframe другого сайта на своем домене?

Tags: jquery, iframe, cors, cross-domain

Есть 2-а сайта (первый - HTTP, второй - HTTPS), оба на одном домене, но каталоги разные. Доступ ко всему есть.
На первом сайте используется `iframe`, в котором выводится второй сайт.
При попытке модифицировать на первом сайте содержимое `iframe` с помощью `jquery` выдается ошибка

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://192.168.45.68" from accessing a frame with origin "null". The
>   frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

Уже неделю изучаю вопрос, не могу найти решение. Насколько понял связано это с Same origin policy (суть его я понял). В качестве решения предлагается настройка CORS. Пробовал его настроить. Сервер на апач. В `htaccess` 2-го сайта (который в `iframe`) включил:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

не помогает, та же ошибка.

Подскажите варианты решения. В этом деле новичок, желательно с простыми примерами.
Годятся любые варианты, не только CORS. Желательно те, что проще в настройке.

Comment: Вариантов особо нет - браузер не даст работать с содержимым, полученным с другого протокола/домена/порта (если не использовать ключики специальные). Подробнее на [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/5011111).

Comment: поскольку домен мой, то любые настройки могут быть сделаны. Вопрос в том, что CORS не получается настроить. В приведенной Вами ссылки рассматривается спец. настройка браузеров - этот вариант не подходит, т.к. должно работать у пользователей без спец. настроек браузера. Другой вариант в ссылке - CORS. Его и не получается настроить. Также из Вашей ссылки: suggests that CORS/Access-Control-Allow-Origin does not apply to iFrames, Не верю, что имея доступ нельзя такое сделать.